# Linux kernel code space write protection

Tags: linux-kernel

I had couple of questions on linux kernel memory page write protection.

1. How can i figure out if the kernel
   code (text segment) is write
   protected or not. I can look at
   `/proc/<process-id>/map` to see the
   memory map for various processes.
   But not sure where to look for the
   kernel code memory map.
2. If the kernel code segment is write
   protected, then is it possible for
   the code segment pages to be
   overwritten by any other kernel
   level code. In other words, does the
   write protect on a text segment page
   protects against only the user space
   code writing to it or will it
   prevent writes even from within the
   kernel space code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Code running in the kernel has direct access to the page tables for the current address space, so it can check for write access by examining those.  There are probably functions to help you with that check, but I'm not familiar enough with the mm code to point them out.  Is there an easier way?  I'm not sure.
2. The kernel text should never be writable from user-space.  The text can additionally be protected against writing from kernel code too (I think this is what you're talking about).  This is only a basic protection against bugs.  Kernel code, if it really wants to, can disable that protection by modifying the page tables directly.

Answer (score 1):

There is one paper talking about that. Basically, it uses a small hypervisor to protect the OS kernel.

SecVisor: A Tiny Hypervisor to Provide Lifetime Kernel Code Integrity for Commodity OSes.

http://www.sosp2007.org/papers/sosp079-seshadri.pdf